# Python function argument *x, what does it mean?

Tags: python, lambda, variadic-functions

I've seen lambda functions, with an argument of `*x`. Is it a way you put in a list or a tuple, if it is a tuple how would you put a list as an argument parameter and vice versa.

If you could link me to some documentation, I would be grateful.

The lambda function in question:

```
import os
add_to_place = lambda *x : os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *x))
```

Thanks in advance. I've deduced that it is a tuple, but I'd like some documentation, just to be sure.

Comment: How does it take list as an input if in this case a tuple is required?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac It takes **any** iterable and converts it to a tuple of arguments

Comment: @jamylak : Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @jamylak: Why is this question marked as a dupe? None of the linked questions mention lambda functions, and I landed on this page when I did a websearch for 'python lambda asterisk'. I have some understanding about lambda functions and the asterisk operator individually, but felt I needed help understanding how they work combined. I do think this question needs a better title, but if it's an 'exact duplicate' of another question, it's not obvious to me which question it duplicates.

Comment: @MichaelScheper It's marked as a dupe because the asterisk is used exactly the same.

Comment: @jamylak: But this question is at least as much about lambda functions as the asterisk operator. And as I said (hopefully you read my whole comment), none of allegedly duplicate questions mention lambda functions at all. Surely, in cases like this, tests for equivalence should be conjunctive, not disjunctive?

Comment: @MichaelScheper It just doesn't seem to be large enough of a distinction to need its own question, since a `lambda` is just an anonymous function and works with the asterisk operator in the exact same way `def` does. Using a `lambda` doesn't change the question enough in my opinion, and I guess it is just an opinion but at least 4 other users also voted to close as duplicate

Comment: @jamylak: I accept that. This question did save me doing further searching, though, so if future readers upvote my comments, maybe you'll reconsider. Otherwise, I'll just accept that my mind, for whatever reason, doesn't combine the two concepts quite as easily as most Python minds. ☺